# Foreign Key query using Query Builder in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I am wondering if it is possible or not to reference a foreign key to a table using the Query Builder instead of using Eloquent relationships.

I am looking at [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations) where we can create foreign key

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

But I don't see in query builder if it is possible to just use the foreign key or references to get all the posts from a user

Do I have to use Eloquent relationships?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins) to query for relations:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'posts.*')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine but this would give an array of user info + post's extra fields each object in the array would include user info which is quite duplicated.  Is there a way to query it so it would give a return of user info with a field including array of post objects such as `{'name': 'hello', 'posts' : [{'title': 'title', 'comments': 'comments'}, {'title': 'title2', 'comments': 'comments2'}]}`

Comment: What I posted is a very basic use of a join clause, to further refine / structure the result set, you'll need to use additional constraints and/or clauses, such as [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset), [Sub-query joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins), [pivots](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereHas), etc. It all very much depends on your database design and goals.